# "Fancy" Class diagrams for printing - visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, class-diagram

I'd like to create a "pretty" diagram based on a bunch of classes in my .Net project. By pretty, I'd like to be able to arrand them in such a way that I could create a nice PDF and potentially even print them to a poster etc. So, instead of the normal class diagram features, Im more interested in the visaul aspects, styling, colorization, and perhaps even being able to hide some functions or attributes that I don't want in the printout.

Any VS addins for this, or a standalone product, or even just some way to export them to a design tool that will let me tune the visual aspects further?

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS Professional, there's the Class Diagram that you can use.  It's not quite as flexible as, say Visio, but it works pretty well if all you're trying to do is keep a current document of what your classes look like, etc.

It's just a file type, like a Class.  Right-click the project, Add-> New Item.  Find Class Diagram on the list of file types.

Comment: Paul, right that's what I'm currently using, and it works fine for what it is, but trying to get "artistic" with the output is not going to happen (nor should it.. it's not mean for pretty pictures). thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Doxygen, I believe that you can customize the graphviz config to stylize the output however you want.